# how to fetch email from different Folders in JAVAMAIL?

Tags: java, email, gmail, jakarta-mail

i'm trying to fetch "**Sent**" folder using JAVAMAIL API but it doesn't work.
actually i checked about existing **Folders** by this code:

```
Store store = emailSession.getStore("imaps");

store.connect(imapHost, user, password);

javax.mail.Folder[] folders = store.getDefaultFolder().list("*");

   for(Folder f : folders) { 
             System.out.println("name: "+f.getName());
           }
```

the Result

```
    name: INBOX
    name: Trash
    name: Sent
    name: Junk
    name: Drafts
```

i tried it with 2 different Email providers (Gmail & Hostinger) and it did not work.. i can fetch the **INBOX** folder but it does not work with **Sent** folder even if i tried it many times with different letter cases...
what is the problem please?

Answer (score 0):

after i did some more researches i found that that **getName()** is not the real name of The folder so if you would like to get The Real Name you have to use getFullname()

```
System.out.println("name: "+f.getFullName());
```

so i got the Full Names and i tried using theim and the Code is Working fine now..